# Can't set :maxlength in ActiveAdmin panel, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Problem:
 I would like to limit input characters for description field. I have done similar function to phone number, but I can't do the same for description field.

**My code:**

This code works:

```
  f.input :phone_number, :input_html => { :class => 'autogrow', :rows => 1, :cols => 2, :maxlength => 8 }
```

This code doesn't work:

```
f.input :description, :input_html => {:class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 10, :maxlength => 200  }
f.input :description_ru, :input_html => {:class => 'autogrow', :rows => 10, :cols => 10, :maxlength => 200  }
```

**Maybe maxlength works just for string type fields ? 
Because maxlength works for phone number (string datatype) and doesn't work for description and description_ru (both are text datatype in database).**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you're right that it works just for string type fields.

This seems to work:

```rb
f.input :myfield, as: :string, input_html: { maxlength: 50 }
```

I just had this problem with a `:text` field, switching to `:string` solved the issue for me.